# Only a portion of my front-end users are getting the full functionality of the application

Tags: database, forms, ms-access

I developed a front-end for a separate department that would allow them to key in data to our back-end table structure. Part of that front-end form includes a message box which opens each time they make a change. To allow them to provide a reason, add the date, etc.

Only certain users are seeing this message box when they use the form. It's not a permissions issue or a compatibility problem with versions of Access. We've looked into that. We're lost as to what it could be.

I know the code we use for the message box uses a particular library in MS Access. Could that be an issue? Anything else that you folks think it might be? We're just looking for possibilities here.

Source Code:

```
Option Compare Database

Private Sub Form_BeforeUpdate(Cancel As Integer)
Dim cmmnt As String
If Me.NewRecord Then
'Calls modAudit function to record new records to Audit Trail


cmmnt = InputBox("What is the reason for adding this record")
If StrPtr(cmmnt) = 0 Then
    Me.Undo
    Exit Sub
Else
    Call AuditChanges("providerID", "NEW", cmmnt)
End If
Else
'Calls modAudit function to record edits to Audit Trail


cmmnt = InputBox("What is the reason for changing the value of this field?")
If StrPtr(cmmnt) = 0 Then
    Me.Undo
    Exit Sub
Else
    Call AuditChanges("providerID", "EDIT", cmmnt)
End If

End If

End Sub
```

Comment: Please post the code that launches the message box.

Comment: *"To allow them to provide a reason, add the date, etc."* - so it's an InputBox, not a MessageBox?

Comment: @ChristopherD. - I edited my original post to include the code.

Comment: [How to debug VBA code](http://www.cpearson.com/excel/DebuggingVBA.aspx) - use Breakpoints and/or `Debug.Print` to see which code is actually executed.

Comment: @Andre - Sorry, yes. They enter their information and then choose either 'Ok' or 'Cancel' and selecting cancel nullifies the change. I'll take a look at that link now.